# discrete math and combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Q: Consider the collection of all strings of length 10 made up from the alphabet 0, 1, 2, and 3. How many strings have weight 3?

My problem with that question is that I don't know what they mean by weight.. and more importantly what they mean by having weight 3. Please explain how to do this question, thanks!

Comment: No clue, but they might mean that the sum of the digits is $3$.

Comment: In coding theory, weight usually means the number of non-zero digits.  Equivalently, it's the Hamming distance between the string and the all-zero string.

Comment: what about this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_%28strings%29

Comment: I am confused now

Comment: But typically mathematicians ask problems where the terms are clearly defined (only economists pose questions where the first task is to infer the meaning of the concepts :-))

Comment: @Fermat How could _weight_ be defined via the concept of _$a$-weight_ such that asking for "weight $3$" makes any sense?

Comment: @mathse I am not sure about the definition!

Comment: @Fermat It was a sincere question ... I thought about it, but I don't see any sensible definition of 'weight' derived from '$a$-weight' such that 'weight $3$' would be a meaningful question to ask for.

Comment: @mathse: The Wikipedia article addresses this issue.  If the alphabet is simply a set, then you are right, but if it is an abelian group, so that there is a distinguished zero element, then you can define _weight_ in addition to $\alpha$-weight.  The definition of weight is simply the number of non-zero elements.  So weight $3$ does make sense.

Comment: @WillOrrick Silly me, I didn't read that part. But I'd be almost certain that the OP's alphabet is not an Abelian group but merely a simple ordinary finite set. Thus, I'd bet a beer that weight means the sum of the digits :)

Comment: @mathse: I'll take your bet!  If you're willing to add the "letters" in your alphabet, then you're thinking of it as abelian group too!  See also [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight).

Answer (score 1):

If they mean that the sum of the digits is three, then you look for the number of solutions of

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=3,$$

where $x_i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Then the number of solutions is $\binom{3+10-1}{10-1}=220$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)).

If they mean that the number of non-zero digits is $3$ then there are $3^3\cdot\binom{10}{3}=27\cdot 120$ choices (there are $3^3$ choices for the $3$ non-zero digits, which can be either $1,2$ or $3$, and they can be distributed among $10$ positions).

Comment: @WillOrrick Yes, that's wrong :) I will have to edit.